# Where do I find a Word 2007 viewer for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

Does anyone know where I can get a Word 2007 viewer for Mac OS X?

I don't want Open Office or TextEdit.

Comment: If it's just for pure viewing, [Quick Look](http://www.apple.com/macosx/what-is-macosx/quick-look.html) is quite good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use a free Word Processor like [AbiWord](http://abisource.org) or [NeoOffice](http://www.neooffice.org/neojava/en/index.php)/[Open Office](http://openoffice.org), which can open Word files?

Comment: I tried Open Office - it opens docx documents terribly!

Comment: I think it depends more on the particular document than on the format. Some documents don't convert well. It's probably Microsoft's fault, since they don't adhere to the ooxml standards they helped define. Just another reason to avoid proprietary document formats whenever you can.

Comment: Yeah non Microsoft programs often don't open the documents perfectly. Pages tries - and it's nor perfect and it's possible you'll be missing whole pages or big sections you don't even know are there.

Answer (score 4):

If you just need to view documents, and not do much editing/creation - [Google Documents](http://docs.google.com) works great, and is free, with no installation or downloads required.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a Hotmail account (or any email account attached to a Windows Live account), you can use the new [Office Web Apps](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/web-apps-help/using-office-web-apps-in-windows-live-HA101231889.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA101785172).  They are surprsingly good and much better than the Google Docs apps, in my opinion.

[image: Word Web App]

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above listed options (OpenOffice is great, BTW):

- iWorks will open these files, I believe. (not a free solution but your mac may have iWorks.)
- Open XML File Format Converter for Mac will allow you to open in earlier versions of Office for Mac (not a free solution either, but you may have a copy of an older version)
- Bean (free but some limitations) www.bean-osx.com/Word97.html
  Word 2007 (.docx) support in Bean:

Bean uses Apple's file conversion services to open and save Word 2007 format files. Please note that due to the limitations of the file format converter, images are lost when opening a native Word 2007 format file in Bean and when saving a rich text document as a Word 2007 format file in Bean. Also lost are highlighting, tables, text lists and advanced paragraph formatting. Sorry, this is how Apple implemented it. The user will be warned of this when overwriting a Word 2007 format file not created by Bean, to prevent loss of information. Bean should not be considered a replacement for Word, or any other word processor designed for complex documents involving, for example, citations.

If you have VMWare fusion, Parallels, or some other virtualization technology and a windows image, you could install the free Windows Word 2007 Viewer.

You could also use these services :

www.docx2doc.com

or docx-converter.com

Answer (score 0):

You could use Open Office for Mac:
(It is the free version of the Office software from Sun.)

http://porting.openoffice.org/mac/

Free download.

Comment: I can use it for new documents but for existing docx document they come out terribly!

Answer (score 0):

TextEdit, bundled with Mac OS X, supports Office 2007 documents since Mac OS X Leopard.

Comment: They come out terribly formatted