# How to view .docx and .doc file on mac os x10.6.5

Tags: mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Word Viewer for Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/191120/word-viewer-for-mac)

I want to view .docx file and .doc file in my mac os x10.6.5.When i open this type of file it shows only text in text editor.The docx file has some more images i didnt able to see.

Is there any default application in my mac to view these two files.Are i want to download some application to view those files ?If yes means what are the application really need for these files ?

Can anyone help me ? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

There is no default application on the Mac, other than Text Editor (which it sounds like you are using), but not to worry; visit Google Docs (https://docs.google.com/), upload the file, and you will be able to view it. Alternatively, the free [Libre Office](http://www.documentfoundation.org/download/) or [Neo Office](http://www.neooffice.org/neojava/en/index.php) can view these files. However, with Google Docs, these files will exist in the cloud, meaning they are automatically backed-up and viewable from any device you own, and so I would recommend using that over downloading Libre Office or Neo Office.

Answer (score 1):

[Open Office for Mac](http://porting.openoffice.org/mac/).

Answer (score 0):

Or you could buy Pages (part of iWork, but wait until 6 January and you can probably buy it by itself in the OS X App Store) or even Office 2011.